# How can I send vcard/contacts/?vcf var SMS or MMS in Android?

Tags: android, sms, mms, vcf-vcard

I want to modify the Android source code that can send (contacts/vcard/.vcf file) by
MMS or SMS, the Android default way is through Bluetooth.
I find a lot of ways, but it all doesn't work.
I know the vcf format is like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:;lybeen;;;
FN:lybeen
TEL;CELL;
PREF:1-123-234-1234
TEL;CELL:000-111-1111
END:VCARD
```

I send this string by SMS as a plain message. Some Android phone can recognize this as a contact, however, most of the Android phone can not recognize, but I don't know how to send the contacts by MMS.

Comment: seems like a more general problem, find more here [example_1](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8179), [example_2](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2412), anyways, it seems not to be a programming specific question.

Comment: I want to realize by programming in android source code, I find it not easy to realize

Comment: @lybeen have you find solution ?

Answer (score 3):

though i think i am late in answering the question, whether it will help the OP or not, but it will always be helpfull for the future visitors.

To send Vcard through mms, you just need to attach the `.vcf` file with the system's intent.

```
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/x-vcard");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: hey friends,I developing a chat application so i want to send contacts in chat like whats app so plz help me that how to get solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

[SmsManager.sendDataMessage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendDataMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20short,%20byte%5B%5D,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

you could probably send the vcard calling method sendDataMessage from SmsManager class. that means you can't send send the vcard as plain message but you need to encode the vcard to hex. or you can probably look at this. http://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to you. Try this with your need -

```
package com.vcard;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class VCardActivity extends Activity 
{
    Cursor cursor;
    ArrayList<String> vCard ;
    String vfile;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        vfile = "Contacts" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".vcf";
        /**This Function For Vcard And here i take one Array List in Which i store every Vcard String of Every Conatact
         * Here i take one Cursor and this cursor is not null and its count>0 than i repeat one loop up to cursor.getcount() means Up to number of phone contacts.
         * And in Every Loop i can make vcard string and store in Array list which i declared as a Global.
         * And in Every Loop i move cursor next and print log in logcat.
         * */
        getVcardString();

    }
    private void getVcardString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vCard = new ArrayList<String>();
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor!=null&&cursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for(int i =0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
            {

                get(cursor);
                Log.d("TAG", "Contact "+(i+1)+"VcF String is"+vCard.get(i));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");
        }

    }

    public void get(Cursor cursor)
    {
        //cursor.moveToFirst();
        String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
        AssetFileDescriptor fd;
        try {
            fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

            // Your Complex Code and you used function without loop so how can you get all Contacts Vcard.??
           /* FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
            fis.read(buf);
            String VCard = new String(buf);
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
            out.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());
            Log.d("Vcard",  VCard);*/

            FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
            fis.read(buf);
            String vcardstring= new String(buf);
            vCard.add(vcardstring);

            String storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
            FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(storage_path, false);
            mFileOutputStream.write(vcardstring.toString().getBytes());

        } catch (Exception e1) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

for more detailed code you may also looke at http://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/downloads/list