# Android - How to send/read vCard via SMS/MMS?

Tags: android, sms, contacts, mms, vcf-vcard

I'm looking for any way to send/read a vCard via SMS in my app. I've read a lot of articles, web-pages, forums etc. There is still not even a clue how to do that.

Here is transaction.

1. User selects some specific contact
2. App generates a vCard for it
3. User types a number to send vCard to
4. App sends SMS with that vCard(?)
5. Addressee recievs SMS with vCard and asked to browse contact/add to
   contacts(?)

Here is some posts in stackoverflow with the same issue: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697735/how-to-send-vcard-as-an-sms-mms) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080849/how-can-i-send-vcard-contacts-vcf-var-sms-or-mms-in-android). Still nothing helpful...

I've found [this nice library](http://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/) to work .vcf files(both write and read). But is there any way to send it to another phone (and read properly of course)? Just send this as a string maybe?

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972905/working-example-of-senddatamessage-for-android) is a nice stack post about handling data from recieved SMS sent by SMSManager.sendDataMessage() method

Please help! I'll be happy to get any clue, useful library or a proof that it's impossible on Android. If there is no way via SMS can you give me advice how to do that via MMS?

What's interesting, that there is a lot of apps with that functionality, so I guess this is possible.

Thanks anyone who responds. Have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to read MMS from code, when you have system for that.

To send MMS with vCard, you need to attach .vcf file to it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420312/android-how-to-attach-file-to-sms) is an answer how to do that.