# How to generate a .vcf file from an object which contains contact detail and object is not in the phone book

Tags: java, android, vcf-vcard

I want to generate a .vcf file for an object which contains contact information like name, image, phone number, fax number, email id, address etc. This object is not added in the address book of the phone but it is stored in my application.

Once my .vcf file is generated I can send this vcard like this

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("**generated.vcf**"), "text/x-vcard");
startActivity(i);
```

But I am not getting how to get this generated .vcf file?

Comment: elaborate your problem. what's object.? have you fetched contact list.? have you created vcard.?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj I think the OP means that he has _an_ object with some person's information in it and he wants to create a vcf out of it; this info has nothing to do with the phone's contacts.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's actually quite easy to generate a .vcf file.  Have a look at [VCF format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) - it's a simple text file.  All you need to do is create text file and write info into it using the VCF fields.  You'll end up with something like this:

```
Person p = getPerson();

File vcfFile = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "generated.vcf");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(vcfFile);
fw.write("BEGIN:VCARD\r\n");
fw.write("VERSION:3.0\r\n");
fw.write("N:" + p.getSurname() + ";" + p.getFirstName() + "\r\n");
fw.write("FN:" + p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getSurname() + "\r\n");
fw.write("ORG:" + p.getCompanyName() + "\r\n");
fw.write("TITLE:" + p.getTitle() + "\r\n");
fw.write("TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:" + p.getWorkPhone() + "\r\n");
fw.write("TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:" + p.getHomePhone() + "\r\n");
fw.write("ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;" + p.getStreet() + ";" + p.getCity() + ";" + p.getState() + ";" + p.getPostcode() + ";" + p.getCountry() + "\r\n");
fw.write("EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:" + p.getEmailAddress() + "\r\n");
fw.write("END:VCARD\r\n");
fw.close();

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(vcfFile), "text/x-vcard");
startActivity(i);
```

(Note that this code is to be placed inside an activity.  If it's not in an activity, then replace `this` in front of `getExternalFilesDir` with an instance of `Context`.)

You can have more of fewer fields, as needed.  If you have `,`, `;` or `\` characters in field values, they need to be escaped with `\`; to put a newline character into a value, write `\\n` into the file (i.e. the file itself must contain `\n`, the second slash is for escaping the slash in the newline).

This code is quite crude, but it should get you started.  Again, have a look at the format of VCF and go from there.

**Update:** Thanks to @Michael for pointing out mistakes in my original answers.

Comment: +1, good explanation. will it send .vcf file as an mms.? is there any way to send vcard string as sms to other phone, because some phones(other than android) dont support mms.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj This question isn't about how to send a VCF but rather about how to generate one.  Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420312/android-how-to-attach-file-to-sms) regarding sending it by SMS.

Comment: I am not talking about this question. I was just asking if you know how to send it as sms.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj The answer is in the question I linked to from my comment.

Comment: @AleksG Colon characters do not need to be escaped in field values.  Also, comma characters should be escaped.  So the characters you should escape are: `;`, `\ `, `,`, and newlines.  Also, the correct newline sequence to use for separating fields is "\r\n" not "\n".

Comment: @Michael Thanks.  I'm updating the answer accordingly.

Comment: @AleksG Np.  I could see how you might be confused about thinking that colons must be escaped.  There are a number of popular mail clients which incorrectly escape colons, such as GMail and the iPhone.

Comment: what if I want to share this contact information with other application, say whatsapp ?? What changes i have to make in above?

Comment: @I-droid I'm not sure what this have to do with this question. Please post a separate question for this - but search to make sure that you don't post duplicates.

Comment: but i am unable to export multiple Contact using for loop using given code

Comment: how to save ,Familyinfromation,birthday,Assistant,website,notes an all can u please tell @AleksG

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123920/how-to-export-all-contact-information-as-vcf-file-in-android  please check this @Akshay

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in using a vCard library instead of creating the vCard string by hand. That way, you don't have to worry about all the formatting details, like which characters to escape.  [ez-vcard](http://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard) is one such library.

Using ez-vcard, the vCard in @AleksG's code sample would be generated like so:

```
Person p = getPerson();

File vcfFile = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "generated.vcf");

VCard vcard = new VCard();
vcard.setVersion(VCardVersion.V3_0);

StructuredNameType n = new StructuredNameType();
n.setFamily(p.getSurname());
n.setGiven(p.getFirstName());
vcard.setStructuredName(n);

vcard.setFormattedName(new FormattedNameType(p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getSurname()));

OrganizationType org = new OrganizationType();
org.addValue(p.getCompanyName());
vcard.setOrganization(org);

vcard.addTitle(new TitleType(p.getTitle()));

TelephoneType tel = new TelephoneType(p.getWorkPhone());
tel.addType(TelephoneTypeParameter.WORK));
tel.addType(TelephoneTypeParameter.VOICE));
vcard.addTelephoneNumber(tel);

tel = new TelephoneType(p.getHomePhone());
tel.addType(TelephoneTypeParameter.HOME));
tel.addType(TelephoneTypeParameter.VOICE));
vcard.addTelephoneNumber(tel);

AddressType adr = new AddressType();
adr.setStreetAddress(p.getStreet());
adr.setLocality(p.getCity());
adr.setRegion(p.getState());
adr.setPostalCode(p.getPostcode());
adr.setCountry(p.getCountry());
adr.addType(AddressTypeParameter.WORK);
vcard.addAddress(adr);

EmailType email = new EmailType(p.getEmailAddress());
email.addType(EmailTypeParameter.PREF);
email.addType(EmailTypeParameter.INTERNET);
vcard.addEmail(email);

vcard.write(vcfFile);

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(vcfFile), "text/x-vcard");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123920/how-to-export-all-contact-information-as-vcf-file-in-android @Michael