# how to export all contact information as VCF file in android

Tags: android

using this code i am able to export what ever value i set but apart from that i want to save image,birthday,relationship,assistnat,notes,Label,website.

How to set this value to generated vcf file?

```
Person p = getPerson();

File vcfFile = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "generated.vcf");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(vcfFile);
fw.write("BEGIN:VCARD\r\n");
fw.write("VERSION:3.0\r\n");
fw.write("N:" + p.getSurname() + ";" + p.getFirstName() + "\r\n");
fw.write("FN:" + p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getSurname() + "\r\n");
fw.write("ORG:" + p.getCompanyName() + "\r\n");
fw.write("TITLE:" + p.getTitle() + "\r\n");
fw.write("TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:" + p.getWorkPhone() + "\r\n");
fw.write("TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:" + p.getHomePhone() + "\r\n");
fw.write("ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;" + p.getStreet() + ";" + p.getCity() + ";" + p.getState() + ";" + p.getPostcode() + ";" + p.getCountry() + "\r\n");
fw.write("EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:" + p.getEmailAddress() + "\r\n");
fw.write("END:VCARD\r\n");
fw.close();

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(vcfFile), "text/x-vcard");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: @James Z please help me in this issue

Answer (score 1):

It's and old tread but I hope it helps

I suggest you to read the documentation for vCard:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2426

For the image:

```
fw.write("PHOTO;VALUE=uri:www.abc.net/pub/logos/abccorp.jpg\r\n");
```

or

```
fw.write("PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:MIICajCCAdOgAwIBAgICBEUwDQYJKoZIhvcN
         AQEEBQAwdzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxLDAqBgNVBAoTI05ldHNjYXBlIENvbW11bm
         ljYXRpb25zIENvcnBvcmF0aW9uMRwwGgYDVQQLExNJbmZvcm1hdGlvbiBTeXN0\r\n");
         //<...the remainder of "B" encoded binary data...>
```

For the birthday:

```
fw.write("BDAY:1996-04-15\r\n");
```

For relationship

```
fw.write("ROLE:Programmer\r\n");
```

For assistant

```
fw.write("AGENT:BEGIN:VCARD\nFN:Susan Thomas\nTEL:+1-919-555-
         1234\nEMAIL\;INTERNET:sthomas@host.com\nEND:VCARD\n\r\n");
```

For notes

```
fw.write("NOTE:This fax number is operational 0800 to 1715
          EST\, Mon-Fri.\r\n");
```

For label:

```
fw.write("LABEL;TYPE=dom,home,postal,parcel:Mr.John Q. Public\, Esq.\n
         Mail Drop: TNE QB\n123 Main Street\nAny Town\, CA  91921-1234
         \nU.S.A.\r\n");
```

All this information is obtained from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2426