# Get contacts and send to server as a vcf file in android

Tags: android, import-contacts

I am trying to convert my contacts to .vcf file in android but it gives an error and can not export contacts.

It gives me an error it goes in the catch block and gives:

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1
```

I want to export my all contacts to server using vcf file

```java
public void getVCF() {
 final String vfile = "Contacts.vcf";
 Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
  null, null, null);
 phones.moveToFirst();
 for (int i = 0; i < phones.getCount(); i++) {
  String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones
   .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
  Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
   ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI,
   lookupKey);
  AssetFileDescriptor fd;
  try {
   fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
   FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
   byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
   fis.read(buf);
   String VCard = new String(buf);
   String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    .toString() + File.separator + vfile;
   FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path,
    true);
   mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());
   phones.moveToNext();
   filevcf = new File(path);
   Log.d("Vcard", VCard);
  } catch (Exception e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: did you request all required permissions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export the Contacts as VCF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147563/export-the-contacts-as-vcf-file)

Comment: Another one -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702357/how-to-generate-a-vcf-file-from-an-object-which-contains-contact-detail-and-obj

Comment: There are many solutions on SO. Did you try any? Also, please post full stack trace, not just a part.

Comment: yes i have given all permissions @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: what does `fd.getDeclaredLength()` return? -1 ???

Comment: yes it gives -1 @pskink

Comment: so you have the answer - you cannot do: `new byte[-1]`

Comment: i didnt get your answer @pskink

Comment: you cannot create an array with length < 0 - how do you imagine an array that has -1 elements?

Comment: so what can i do?@pskink

Comment: i would do `byte[] buf = new byte[1024];` for such vcard buffer - but of course you have to check what is the average size of your data and adjust it if its much bigger